# Odoo internal server error on Windows 10. Odoo server couldn't be started [Odoo 10.0]

Tags: windows-10, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I'm having an issue twice after installing Odoo on my Windows 10. At first, I took re-installing the odoo as the solution. And now I'm having the same problem once again, I want to know how to solve it in a proper way. My PostgreSQL_for_odoo managed to Start (Properties: Startup Type - Automatic). But the problem now is the odoo-server doesn't want to start (Properties: Startup Type - Automatic)

This is what I'm suffering when trying to start the odoo-server [Starting the odoo service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0BdC.png)

Inside the odoo-server properties [Odoo server properties (Log On)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHViH.png)

This is the odoo-server log file
[Odoo-server.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwohw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try with https://nightly.odoo.com/10.0/nightly/exe/
uninstall all the odoo packages ,postgres , python and also delete all the services releated odoo package, change port number if you have any error on it.
     If you have error after this, change your directory and reinstall